# Sony Xperia Z1 Compact Sony Enterprise API

Tags: android, sony, mdm, sony-xperia

Does anyone know what Enterprise API version the Z1 Compact support?

I have installed the Airwatch Sony Service which states: Currently, devices with Sony enterprise API version 3-5 have been certified by AirWatch.

But I can't find any info on what API my phone has, and if that is why my Mail account does not work trough Airwatch.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment (November 2014) Z1 on the latest software update (4.4) supports Enterprise API level 4. That can change with future updates.